# How do you inherit from emotion js?

Tags: javascript, emotion

```
const Button = styled.button`
  color: palevioletred;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;

const TomatoButton = styled(Button)`
  color: tomato;
  border-color: tomato;
`;
```

When inheriting from styled-component, the code above works

```
export const containerBooks=css({
    display: 'grid',
    gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(2, minmax(300px, 1fr))',
    gridGap: '100px',
    padding: '50px',
    width: '70%',
    paddingTop: '50px'
});
```

How should I code when trying to inherit containerBooks from emotion?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Watch the video on this link, it explains it

https://egghead.io/lessons/react-inherit-styles-using-css-composition-with-react-emotion-s-css-import